# Rxjs: Returning value with take

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is the function below the right way to get value from an Observable and return it synchronously?

```
getAllTags = (): Array<TagModel> =>{
        var to_ret = new Array<TagModel>();
        this.ngrxStateList.take(1).subscribe(x=>to_ret = x );
        return to_ret;
    }
```

Or should I return the value as a promise?

**NOTE:** The observable is basically a list in ngrx state.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, it works but not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Your test is wrong. This will return an empty array if the observable emits asynchronously, since you will return the array before the subscribe callback is invoked. You can't transform an asynchronous call into a synchronous one. Forget about this idea. It's a dead-end. Just return the observable, and let the caller subscribe to access the emitted events.

Comment: @JBNizet Checkout the update, please not the observable is basically a list store in ngrx state. And I only need to access the list once, immediately.

Comment: Still, it's a bad idea. If it's modeled as an observable, it's because it could be asynchronous. Don't make the assumption that it is synchronous, and use observables as they should be used.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the function below the right way to get value from an Observable and return it synchronously?

Trying to return a value synchronously from something asynchronous is never a good idea. No matter if it's a Promise or an Observable.

> Or should I return the value as a promise?

You already have an Observable, why would you return a Promise? Just keep it as an Observable :)

I think that your workflow should be:
 - have a service where you retrieve your list over HTTP
 - have an effect waiting for the action FETCH_LIST, which then call your service, and once it has the result dispatch an action FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS with the list as payload, and then your reducer add the list to the store
 - in your component, just have the following:

```
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  public tags$: TagModel[] = this
    .store
    .select(state => state.select.the.good.slice.of.state);

  constructor (private store: Store<YourStoreType>) {} 
}
```

and within your HTML view:

```
<div *ngIf="tags$ | async as tags; else #noTags">
  Your list has {{ tags.length }} tag{{ tags.length > 1 ? 's': '' }}

  List:
  <div *ngFor="let tag of tags">
    {{ tag.theTagPropertyYouWantToDisplay }}
  </div>
</div>

<div #noTags>
  No tags available yet!
</div>
```

Fully reactive example :) now every time you want to refresh your list, just dispatch another `FETCH_LIST` action, which will be caught by the effect, which will fetch the tags, update the store and thanks to the observable + Angular, your list will be automatically updated in the view.